How to reproduce the pressure, tilt, orientation in line stroke of the Path using a Stylus Pen in Kotlin?

I followed this instructions
(https://developer.android.com/codelabs/large-screens/advanced-stylus-support#3
to draw on the Android Tablet screen with Stylus Pen.
I am using a Samsung Tab S6 Lite with S-Pen
I can notice the pressure, tilt and orientation reproduced at the top of the demo.
It's working fine.
But how can I reproduce this pressure in line stroke of the path in the draw real time?
Because the StylusStates represents all draws in the screen, and if I apply a pressure to stylusStates it will apply to all draws in the screen.
@Composable
   @OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
   fun DrawArea(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
      Canvas(modifier = modifier
          .clipToBounds()
          .pointerInteropFilter {
              viewModel.processMotionEvent(it)
          }
      ) {
          with(stylusState) {
              drawPath(
                  path = this.path,
                  color = Color.Gray,
                  style = strokeStyle
              )
          }
      }
   }

class StylusViewModel : ViewModel() {

   ...

   fun processMotionEvent(motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {

      ...
         else -> return false
      }


      requestRendering(
         StylusState(
             tilt = motionEvent.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_TILT),
             pressure = motionEvent.pressure,
             orientation = motionEvent.orientation,
             path = createPath()
         )
      )

I need to apply I think point by point at the moment while drawing. So the drawing will capture all pressure variations and reproduce a real handwrite with different point of pressure while handwriting.
Does any one know how to reproduce this pressure in the line stroke?
Also I tried to apply different color to Paths, but if I apply to StylusStates it will apply to all draws not the new ones.
